# how to use nested select query in knex

Tags: node.js, knex.js

I want to add a sub-query as a column using knex. 
Example SQL query:

```
select
    name, 
    (select count(*) from employee where employee.dept_id = 1) as employees_count
 from 
    department
 where
    department.id = 1
```

I tried

```
knex('department').select('name', knex('employee').count().where({dept_id: 1}))
.where({id: 1})
```

but it didn't work

Answer (score 2):

```
const Knex = require('knex');


const knex = Knex({
  client: 'pg',
});

knex('department').select(
  'name', 
  knex('employee').count().where({dept_id: 1})
    .as('employees_count')
).where({id: 1}).toSQL().sql;

// "select \"name\", (select count(*) from \"employee\" where… \"employees_count\" from \"department\" where \"id\" = ?"
```

https://runkit.com/embed/q22w8v6z5n61

Answer (score 0):

To help yourself localize the issue, you can add `.debug()` to your querybuilder. That allows you to see the actual rendered query. This will not solve your issue, but will give you insight into how Knex sees your query.

To solve your issue, try some combination of `select` and `raw`. Like:

```
let emp = knex('employee').count().where({ dept_id: 1 })
knex('department')
.select('name')
.select(knex.raw('? as employee_count', emp))
//.debug()
```

use `.debug()` to clear out minor issues.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to "join" employee to department like

```
(select count(*) from employee where dept_id = departament.id) as employees_count
```

you can try Mikael's solution with whereRaw

```
knex('department').select([
  'name', 
  knex('employee')
    .count()
    .whereRaw('employee.dept_id = department.id')
    .as('employees_count'),
]).where({id: 1})
```